# vertical text with dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I m using dompdf to generate contract each time I click in a specific link, And I need to do vertical side that exist in every page(if contract> 1page )But I don't know how
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer

**NO**

As far as I know **dompdf** is only CSS 2.1 compliant and rotating text appears first time  in CSS3.

**... hmm**

The only trick that you can try is to create a picture with GD that contains the text you desire to rotate. [There is a nice example here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/gd-help-rotate-the-text-with-imagestring/2292) that I copied down here, because sometimes sites go offline and the links die unexpectedly.

```php
$label = "TEXT YOU WANT TO ROTATE";
$labelfont = 2;

// pixel-width of label
$txtsz = imagefontwidth($labelfont) * strlen($label);
// pixel-height of label
$txtht = imagefontheight($labelfont);

// define temp image
$labelimage = imagecreate($txtsz, $txtsz);
$white = imagecolorallocate($labelimage, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$black = imagecolorallocate($labelimage, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

// write to the temp image
imagestring($labelimage, $labelfont, 0, $txtsz/2 - $txtht/2, $label , $black);

// rotate the temp image
$labelimage1 = imagerotate($labelimage, 90, $white);

// copy the temp image back to the real image
imagecopy($image, $labelimage1, 3, $vmargin + $ysize/2 - $txtsz/2, $txtsz/2 - $txtht/2, 0, $txtht, $txtsz);

// destroy temp images, clear memory
imagedestroy($labelimage);
imagedestroy($labelimage1);
```